# shutil.make_archive [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem using shutil.make_archive,I didn't understand why the code worked day by day, it remains in the structure below, but with a new commit, having an update in another script, and from there it started to fail, I traced the error in the terminal. Where that code is located doesn't matter at all from the other script. Now I'm in this error.

code:

```py
shutil.make_archive(output_folder, 'zip', '.', output_folder)
```

output erro:

```bash
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IMAGES'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search in the documentation, [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). I managed to understand what the problem was because I passed two paths the "output_folder". I removed one it and no longer needed it. Code execute.

code:

```py
shutil.make_archive(output_folder, 'zip', '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we try running the code on a Javascript browser. Looks like there are some cookie issues which can be resolved by reconnecting to the network after running the pip install command to install the missing packages

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve